# Background image with sass variable Not resolved

Tags: html, css, variables, sass, background-image

I used this code  painted all items on body, I need only  image on the body background

```
$fondo: url(/grid/assets/img/backimage.png);

{ padding: 0; margin: 0; } body { ::before{

content:"" ; height: 1008px; width: 100%; display: flex; position: absolute; 
background-image: $fondo ; background-repeat: no-repeat ; background-position: 
center; background-size: cover; filter: blur(1.6rem);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
$fondo: url(/grid/assets/img/backimage.png);
 body { 
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
     &::before{
        content:"" ; 
        height: 1008px; 
        width: 100%; 
        display: flex; 
        position: absolute; 
        background-image: $fondo;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center; 
        background-size: cover; filter: blur(1.6rem);
    }
}
```